# How to remove entity with OneToMany relation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have class Building with:

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "building")
private List<Floor> floorList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and on the other side:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "BUILDING_ID")
private Building building;
```

And now I cannot remove Building at all, when I try to deleteById(id) then this error occured:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Naruszenie więzów integralności: "FKNRVYGRFI0C51V0GF7JI9KF4QK: PUBLIC.ASSET FOREIGN KEY(FLOOR_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.FLOOR(ID) (129)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKNRVYGRFI0C51V0GF7JI9KF4QK: PUBLIC.ASSET FOREIGN KEY(FLOOR_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.FLOOR(ID) (129)"; SQL statement:
delete from floor where id=? [23503-200]
```

I have tried cascade = CascadeType.ALL, MERGE, REMOVE, and without cascade and nothing is working. The only way to remove Building is a situation when all of the floors are deleted first (floorList is empty).

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the `Building` - `Floor` association, Hibernate is actually trying to `delete from` the `floor` table, as the log is telling you. There is another table `ASSET`, and a row in that table is referencing one of the `floor` rows to be deleted, via the `floor_id` column. You can literally read all that from the error message